# Fault Recovery of a UAV using MATLAB

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, control-theory, complex-dynamics, transfer-theory

I'm currently investigating fault recovery in a UAV using MATLAB.

*I've been given several variables:*

- **phi** = the roll angle
- **psi** = the yaw/heading angle
- **beta** = the side slip
- **p** = roll rate
- **r** = yaw/heading rate
- **delta_r** = angle of the rudder
- **delta_a** = angle of the aileron (the aileron is currently inactive).

**My input is the rudder angle.**

**I've simulated a step fault in the yaw/heading sensor and I'm trying to recover from it.**

*To detect that there was a fault in the heading sensors:* I compared the actual side-slip with the modeled side slip. If there is a difference between the "real' system and the model in heading angle, but no difference in side-slip, then the heading sensor is faulty.

*To recover from this fault:* I want to reconfigure the side-slip so I can use it to determine the heading/yaw angle. In order to do this I need to multiply the side-slip by the transfer function between side-slip and heading/yaw angle.

**We've been given the following equations:**

[image]

**I'm having some trouble coming up with a transfer function between side slip and heading angle.**

*I figured the best thing to do, as I am using a simulation filled with arrays, is to turn all the derivatives into their discrete equivalent* - of course this is means I'm not using a transfer function, but an equation. Taking the equation for the derivative of beta and discretizing it...

[image]

**When I plug this in, the system doesn't recover.**

**I even tried doing Laplace transforms**, *but I get stuck here:*

[image]

**And I'm not sure how I could apply that in MATLAB**

*Is there a mistake in my logic or approach?* *How would I turn the discrete system into a transfer function?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -19.4399 \beta (t)+78.4002 \delta_a(t)-2.7282 \delta_r(t)-p'(t)-11.454 p(t)+2.7185 r(t)& = & 0 \\
 23.3434 \beta (t)-3.469 \delta_a(t)+13.9685 \delta_r(t)+0.5068 p(t)-r'(t)-2.9875 r(t) & = & 0\\
 -\beta '(t)-0.468 \beta (t)+0.0922 p(t)+0.3256 \phi (t)-0.9957 r(t) & = & 0\\
 p(t)-\phi '(t)+0.0926 r(t) & = & 0\\
 r(t)-\psi '(t) & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Taking the equations Laplace transform with null initial conditions we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -19.4399 B(s)+78.4002 \delta_a(s)-2.7282 \delta_r(s)- s P(s)-11.454 P(s)+2.7185 R(s) & = & 0 \\
 23.3434 B(s)-3.469 \delta_a(s)+13.9685 \delta_r(s)+0.5068 P(s)-sR(s) -2.9875 R(s) & = & 0 \\
 -s B(s)-0.468 B(s)+0.0922 P(s)+0.3256 \Phi(s)-0.9957 R(s) & = & 0 \\
 P(s)-s\Phi(s)+0.0926 R(s) & = & 0 \\
 R(s)-s\Psi(s) & = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving now for $\{P(s),R(s),B(s),\Phi(s),\Psi(s)\}$ and substituting into $\frac{\Psi(s)}{B(s)}$ with $\delta_a(s)=0$ we have

$$
\frac{\Psi(s)}{B(s)} = \frac{-13.9685 s^4-161.282 s^3-47.6704 s^2-41.821 s+18.7384}{14.16 s^4+151.728 s^3-57.5869 s^2+4.01257 s}
$$

NOTE

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 -s-11.454 & 2.7185 & -19.4399 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.5068 & -s-2.9875 & 23.3434 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.0922 & -0.9957 & -s-0.468 & 0.3256 & 0 \\
 1 & 0.0926 & 0 & -s & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -s \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 P(s) \\
 R(s) \\
 B(s) \\
 \Phi(s) \\
 \Psi(s) \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 78.4002 \delta_a(s)-2.7282 \delta_r(s) \\
 -3.469 \delta_a(s)+13.9685 \delta_r(s) \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This system can be symbolically solved using the Symbolic Matlab Toolbox.

This transfer function can be reduced by "cancelling" $(s+11.2678)$ in the numerator with $(s+11.0844)$ in the denominator.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply and insight it is much appreciated. I would really like to learn how to do this properly. I hope you dont mind but would you mind clarifying if you took the laplace of all of them and then systematically solved for phi, from the last equation upwards?

Comment: Added additional steps.

Comment: What is the best way to implement these functions? Could I just say output = sysTF*input? Sorry if that is a basic question, all the documentation I have found leaves off at "and your transfer function is given by ss(A,B,C,D)". Thank you for your time